# How to deploy custom .dll commands in ArcMap 9.3.2?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

In ArcMAp 9.3.2, I am trying to bring in an acreage calculator .dll buttom that I have used on previous versions.  The .dll doesn't show up on the list of available custom addons.  Is this a registration problem?  I'm at a loss of what could be causing the .dll to not be available on the list.

Comment: ArcMap 9.3.2? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

If your dll is registered correctly, make sure your control is part of the "MxCommands" component category

In C#

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for ArcGIS Component Category registration -
    /// Do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private static void ArcGISCategoryRegistration(Type registerType)
    {
        string regKey = string.Format("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{{{0}}}", registerType.GUID);
        MxCommands.Register(regKey);

    }
```

In c++

```
[
coclass,
default(IADCommandShowPredefinedQuery),
threading(apartment),
vi_progid("ACAGISExt.ADAqCommandShowPr"),
progid("ACAGISExt.ADAqCommandShPr.1"),
version(1.0),
uuid("B708424D-C917-457F-B414-E0EB6313CC14"),
helpstring("ADAqCommandShowPredefinedQuery Class"),
implements_category(__uuidof(CATID_MxCommands)) //<<-- Component Category here 
]
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CADAqCommandShowPredefinedQuery :
public CADCommandShowPredefinedQuery
{
    //Implementation here
};
```

Comment: Registered MXCommands may be found in Cateogries.exe, e.g. location C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Bin\Categories.exe

Answer (score 0):

Heres how it goes if i remember correctly: Right click on an empty space where the toolbars are located, select Customize, go to Commands tab and choose Add from file. Then you select your plugin dll.

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually I think you need to select the .tlb (.tbl?) file. Selecting the DLL gets you nowhere. This of course assumes you've registered using regasm if .NET or regsvr if VB